# error when transfering my existing drupal site to Acquia desktop

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I've installed Acquia but am having trouble getting our website onto it.
I've backed up our website as a local copy on my PC and have created the mysql dump file and plugged it in. When I point the mysql database I get the following error:

> This folder contains a site that is configured for a different MySQL
>   database server. If you continue, new database settings will be added
>   to the site's settings.php so it will work in Dev Desktop, and it will
>   no longer work using that other MySQL database server. Do you want to
>   continue?

```
Array
(
[datbase]=>censored
[username]=> webadmin
[host] => localhost
[port] =>
[driver] => mysql
[prefix] =>
)
```

Can you tell me what went wrong?